# How to use Speech to Text in GDK

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I have a problem when using Speech to Text in GDK. Even though they said it uses Android API Level 15 when I install it onto Glass, it doesn't work, but it works on the phone.

Have you tried this or do you have any idea of implementing it on Glass

Google Glass cards interface has option "Read Aloud" and when we tap it, it works.

Should I use Mirror API or something else to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073695/how-to-install-speech-to-text-in-google-glass

Comment: thank you.I will check that

Comment: We install VoiceSearch apk and now it is working

Answer (score 0):

If your GLASS is XE8 or older you need voicesearch.apk installed in the GLASS to enable voice to text.
But if you are using XE9 or later, the feature is available. you dont have to install voicesearch.apk